# How do you obtain time-based paths?

Tags: datetime, time, path

I am working on a script for a Linux machine to look through a time-based path at a certain time, but I have no experience with time-based paths and resources on this topic seem quite limited even though this should be pretty straightforward.

An example would be to look into the path `/home/temp/test/[Current Date]`. I vaguely remember it being along the lines of `/home/temp/test/%m/%d/%y`, but I am not confident. Within `/home/temp/`, there will be multiple directories with separate dates. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a time-based path? Can you provide a link to any documentation describing a time-based path?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any documentation on this. From my understanding, it is a path that contains a time-related variable. So /home/temp/test/%m should be /home/temp/test/october since %m should denote the month. That's the desired effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so through some more testing, I figured it out. It was pretty close to what I initially had. To specify the time in the path, it really is as straight forward as /home/temp/test/%Y%d%m. I made the mistake of attempting to glob which was a separate error and I interpreted as a related error. Sorry about that.